# Select most highly represented values in a list

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list of (100s of millions of) values, e.g.:

```
echo -e "y\ny\ny\nu\ni\no\no\nl\no\nj\nk\nl\nk\nl\nk\nl\nk\nl\nk\nl\no\nu\no\no\nu\ny\nl\ni\nq\nw\ne\nr\nt\na\ns" > list.txt
```

I want to count how many times each value appears in the list and then select the most common values that represent an arbitrary fraction of the entries on the list (`keep`). I don't care about breaking ties in my actual data set.

My current working code uses `sort | uniq | sort` and `awk`:

```
keep=0.50
sort list.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr > temp
awk -v keep=$keep 'NR==FNR {s+=$1}; NR!=FNR {c+=$1; print $0}; c > (s * keep) {exit 0}' temp temp
      7 l
      6 o
      5 k
```

However, both bits of code seem super clunky. Is there a better way to do this? I'm having trouble finding the right search terms (hence the terrible title on this question).

Comment: Does it have to be in bash? It's way easier in other languages, like Python.

Comment: I've been putting off learning python, but maybe this is the push I need!

Comment: if the values are few known values (like multiple choice yes/no) you could just count each value on its own with `grep -c`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, to state my answer a little more clearly, I would prefer `awk` or `bash` since those are the languages I'm most comfortable with (other than `R`, which seems like overkill). But any reasonable one liner would work.

Comment: What's the output of `sort -u list.txt | wc -c` ? If it's really big, that might limit the use of some utilities that keep everything in memory.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, the output is 139340.

Comment: Cool. Then almost any solution that uses a hash table should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single `awk` command, GNU version to sort the array unique based on the value it contains. The `count` is an associative array, which uniquely counts the occurrence of each line in the file.

The `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_type_desc"` is a GNU `awk` construct, which sorts the entries in the array `count` by descending order of the values. You then iterate over it to sum the occurrence and print the high frequency pair until the the exit condition is matched.

```
awk -v keep=0.50 '
{
    count[$0]++
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_type_desc"
    for (i in count) {
        sum += count[i]
        print i, count[i]
        if (sum > (NR * keep)) {
            break
        }
    }
}' list.txt
```